# In magento 1.6.2.0, generating "maintenance.flag" file when site down and site stop working

Tags: magento-1.6, maintenance

I am facing a problem in Magento 1.6.2.0. It stops running and creates a "maintenance.flag" file. When i delete "maintenance.flag", the site is working again.

In log file it is showing the below error:

exception log:

```
ERR (3): exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:82
ERR (3): exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Parent directory does not exist: catalog' in app/Mage.php:563
```

System log:

```
ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in app/design/frontend/default/themename/template/page/1column.phtml on line 47
ERR (3): Deprecated functionality: Function split() is deprecated  in app/design/frontend/default/themename/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml on line 40
```

How can I fix this issue.

Please help!

Comment: check mysql server logs for the error.

Comment: Thanks.
It is showing error like this [access_compat:error] [pid 1468] [client ip:49763] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: app/etc/local.xml

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the exception "MySQl has gone away" 
This is mostly due to any of the below two reasons

1. Server timed out and closed the connection. 
   fix: try increasing the `wait_timeout` variable in your mysqld’s `my.cnf/my.ini`  configuration file.
2. Server dropped an incorrect or too large packet. 
   fix : increase the maximal packet size limit by increasing the value of `max_allowed_packet` in `my.cnf/my.ini`  file.

Please check in files if you are trying to get something that is taking too long or inapplicable.

Regarding parent directory exception 
Paste the exception backtrace in the question.

Comment: But on same server other magento site working fine. So i think this is not server issue.

Comment: May be some query on one website is taking too long.